# How to make this JS animation effect reverse before it restart?

Tags: javascript, css, anime.js

this is demo text that is animated when it will start animation then this completely disappear and restart.
But I want to restart it first reverse animation then restart.

```js
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.rks1');

textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
  return `<span class="word">` +
    m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
    `</span>`;
});

anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.rks1 .letter',
    scale: [3,1],
    scaleY: [1.5,1],
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 400,
    delay: (el, i) => 60*i
  }).add({
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 800
  });
```

```css
.rks1 {
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 2.5em;
font-family: rr;
}

.rks1 .letter {
display: inline-block;
line-height: 1em;
}

.word {
white-space: nowrap;
}

.span {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
 <h1 class="rks1">
this is demo text that is animated when it will start animation then this completely disappear and restart.
But I want to reverse animation before it restart.
</h1>
```

**& one more feature i want to add in this JS that is like, html lines that animate one by one for example:**

```
<h1 class="rks1"> this is demo text that is animated first then reverse animation & start next line animation
    </h1>

Just like
<h1 class="rks1">  Then Second Line </h1>
<h1 class="rks1">  Then Third Line </h1>
<h1 class="rks1">  Then Fourth Line </h1>
<h1 class="rks1">  Then Fifth Line </h1>
```

& more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`direction`](https://animejs.com/documentation/#direction) property in the animation parameters object to `'alternate'` to go front start to end, and when completed from end to start.

```js
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.rks1');

textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
  return `<span class="word">` +
    m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
    `</span>`;
});

anime.timeline({
  loop: true,
  direction: 'alternate'
})
  .add({
    targets: '.rks1 .letter',
    scale: [3,1],
    scaleY: [1.5,1],
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 400,
    delay: (el, i) => 60*i
  }).add({
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 800
  });
```

```css
.rks1 {
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 2.5em;
font-family: rr;
}

.rks1 .letter {
display: inline-block;
line-height: 1em;
}

.word {
white-space: nowrap;
}

.span {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
 <h1 class="rks1">
this is demo text that is animated when it will start animation then this completely disappear and restart.
But I want to reverse animation before it restart.
</h1>
```

Or add another animation to your timeline with the animation reversed by reversing the selection of the elements that you want to animate.

```js
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.rks1');

textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/(\S*)/g, m => {
  return `<span class="word">` +
    m.replace(/(-|)?\S(-|@)?/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
    `</span>`;
});

var targets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.rks1 .letter'));

anime.timeline({
  loop: true,
})
  .add({
    targets: targets,
    scale: [3,1],
    scaleY: [1.5,1],
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 400,
    delay: (el, i) => 60*i
  }).add({
    targets: targets.reverse(),
    scale: [1,3],
    scaleY: [1,1.5],
    opacity: [1,0],
    translateZ: 0,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 100,
    delay: (el, i) => 30*i
  }).add({
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 800
  });
```

```css
.rks1 {
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 2.5em;
font-family: rr;
}

.rks1 .letter {
display: inline-block;
line-height: 1em;
}

.word {
white-space: nowrap;
}

.span {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<h1 class="rks1">
this is demo text that is animated when it will start animation then this completely disappear and restart.
But I want to reverse animation before it restart.
</h1>
```

Comment: Can i change only direction: 'alternate' or reverse animation speed

Comment: & one more feature i want to add in this JS that is like, html lines that animate one by one for example:

```

Comment: ```
<h1 class="rks1"> this is demo text that is animated first then reverse animation & start next line animation
    </h1>

Just like
<h1 class="rks1">  Then Second Line </h1>
<h1 class="rks1">  Then Third Line </h1>
<h1 class="rks1">  Then Fourth Line </h1>
<h1 class="rks1">  Then Fifth Line </h1>
```

Comment: You can either add the `'alternate'` direction or simply add a new animation which runs backwards with a different speed after the first animation is completed. But that is up to you.

Comment: plz help me how can i add a new animation which runs backwards with a different speed after the first animation is completed. & that looks like reverse effect.

Comment: Check the second example.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Emiel Zuurbier :)
Love You Dear.

it will be more pleasure for me if you can solve my one more problem:
that is i asked :

& one more feature i want to add in this JS that is like, html lines that animate one by one for example:

```
<h1 class="rks1"> this is demo text that is animated first then reverse animation & start next line animation
    </h1>

Just like
<h1 class="rks1">  Then Second Line </h1>
<h1 class="rks1">  Then Third Line </h1>
<h1 class="rks1">  Then Fourth Line </h1>
<h1 class="rks1">  Then Fifth Line </h1>
& after last start first line 
```